# Java: sort 1d array of objects by full or not

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to compress an array of objects that will have empty items interspersed with complete items.  I want to put all the full elements at the start in the same order they started with, and the empty elements on the end.

The object in question uses a String field, "name", and an int field, "weight".  An empty version has "no name" and 0 respectively.  So an array of the type the method needs to deal with will contain something like:

- Fred | 4
- Bob | 3
- no name | 0
- Gina | 9
- no name | 0
- Yuki | 7

After feeding through the method, the array should go Fred, Bob, Gina, Yuki, no name, no name.

My thought for step one was to just figure out which were full and which weren't, so I came up with this:

```
public void consolidate() {
    boolean[] fullSlots = new boolean[spaces.length];

    // pass 1: find empties
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        fullSlots[i] = spaces[i].getName().equals("no name");
    }
}
```

spaces is the array of objects, getName() retrieves the name field from the object.

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Suggestions?

EDIT:  Okay, here's what Infested came up with:

```
public void consolidate()
{
    int numberOfEmpties = 0, spacesLength = spaces.length;
    Chicken[] spaces2 = new Chicken[spacesLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++)
    {
        spaces2[i] = new Chicken(spaces[i].getName(),
                                        spaces[i].getWeight());
    }

    // pass 1: find empties
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < spacesLength; i++)
    {
        if (spaces2[i].getName().equals("no name") == false)
        {
            spaces[j] = new Chicken(spaces2[i].getName(),
                                        spaces2[i].getWeight());
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfEmpties++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = spacesLength - 1; numberOfEmpties > 0 ; numberOfEmpties--, i--)
    {
       spaces[i] = new Chicken("no name", 0);
    }
}
```

Tested and working.

Comment: where are you sorting you string?

Comment: I'm not.  The idea is to sort full objects to the beginning and empty objects to the end, without changing the order of the full objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ill assume its a method of the class:

```
public void consolidate()
{
    int lengthOfSpaces = spaces.length , i, numberOfEmpties = 0;
    Type[] spacesNumberTwo = new Type[lengthOfSpaces ];

    // pass 1: find empties
    for (i = 0; i < lengthOfSpaces ; i++)
    {
        if(spaces[i].getName().equals("no name") == false)
             spacesNumberTwo[i] = new Type(spaces[i].getName(), spaces[i].getInt());
        else
          numberOfEmpties++;
    }
    for (i = lengthOfSpaces - 1; numberOfEmpties > 0 ; numberOfEmpties--, i--)
    {
           spacesNumberTwo[i] = new Type("no name", 0);
    }
    spaces = spacesNumberTwo
}
```

Comment: i = lengthOfSpaces -1;
note that, youll get an overflow here if you dont edit it.

Comment: I'm guessing Type is a placeholder for the object?

Comment: actually, im not sure if it would nullify spaces, as spacesNumberTwo is probably deleted when you exit the method.
so simply copy the whole thing as it is to spacesNumberTwo and switch them around.

Comment: Type is a placeholder for the object

Comment: Still coding a test program.

Comment: just do the following:

Type[] myArrayOfTypeForTest = { {"F",1} {"no name",o} {"a",2} {"no name",o} {"c",3} {"u",5} };

Comment: Dammit.  I'm hitting a java.lang.NullPointerException in my toString() method for the object.

Comment: put it here in a new answer then. we will solve this challenge. also we could teamview to make it much faster if youd like.

Comment: This is my first time using this site.  How does teamview work?

Comment: teamviewer isnt on this site...  
 
http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx

Comment: Okay, it's installed, but this site doesn't seem to have a private message function.

Comment: no it doesnt. email me at arielipi@walla.com your id and password(note, passwords change if you close the teamviewer)

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Arrays.sort` is *stable*, meaning that the relative order of equal elements is not going to change.

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

You can use this property of the sorting algorithm to sort all your elements with a simple comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(
    spaces
,   new Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
              MyClass a = (MyClass)o1;
              MyClass b = (MyClass)o2;
              boolean aIsEmpty = "no name".equals(a.getName());
              boolean bIsEmpty = "no name".equals(b.getName());
              if (aIsEmpty && !bIsEmpty) {
                  return 1;
              }
              if (!aIsEmpty && bIsEmpty) {
                  return -1;
              }
              return 0;
          }
    }
);
```

This will sort all items with non-empty names ahead of the items with empty names, leaving the relative order of both groups of objects unchanged within their respective group.

If your space constraints allow you to create a new array of `MyClass`, you can go for a simpler algorithm: go through the original array once, and make a count of non-empty items. Then create a new array, and make two indexes: `idxNonEmpty = 0`, and `idxEmpty = NonEmptyCount+1`. Then go through the original array one more time, writing non-empty objects to `idxNonEmpty++`, and empty objects to `idxEmpty++`.

Comment: Um.  We haven't studied comparators yet.  I'm sure that would work but unfortunately I have no idea what any of it means.

Comment: @StarSword Try the second algorithm then, it's a lot more approachable. If it's for studying purposes, I'm certain that you would not have issues with allocating a second array.